# Cucumber-jvm: Setting up environment before executing any features

Tags: java, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I want to set environment (e.g. local, dev, prod) once and prior to running any of features.It is to set base url and loading particular test data file. Below is the sample method that I want to invoke once and first thing in my tests. Please suggest the best way to do it.

```
public void  baseSetUp(String environment){
        loadTestData = loadPropertiesFile(enviroment);
        setBaseUrl(enviroment);
        restUtil = new RestUtil(pilotBaseUrl);
        initialSetUp();
    }
```

I am newbie to cucumber and java.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use @Before annotation hooks in the stepDef class for setting up data prior to running the feature file.

```
import cucumber.annotation.After;
import cucumber.annotation.Before;

@Before
public void  baseSetUp(String environment){
        loadTestData = loadPropertiesFile(enviroment);
        setBaseUrl(enviroment);
        restUtil = new RestUtil(pilotBaseUrl);
        initialSetUp();
    }
@Given("^I am doing step 1$")
public void ...... ...
.... 
.. 
.
```

You can integrate TestNG with Cucumber-JVM , if you want to do more custom actions before and after class/suite/feature step.

Comment: Thanks Manmohan for your suggestion. I tried it but it gives an error, it says only argument type Scenario is allowed not String. Here's the error:
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: When a hook declares an argument it must be of type cucumber.api.Scenario. public void utils.CommonUtil.baseSetUp(java.lang.String)

Comment: You need to add **cucumber-core** lib to your project. Also check your IDE default settings for main class where it might be cucumber.cli.Main. you have to change this to cucumber.api.cli.Main

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it by using cucumber with TestNG. In this way, I was able to use annotations of TestNG as well as cucumber hooks. TestNG executes your feature files. Below is the Runner class:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.testng.CucumberFeatureWrapper;
import cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;  
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.testng.annotations.*;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        monochrome = true,
        features = "src/test/java/features",    
        glue = {"utils","steps"},
        tags = {"@test"},
        format = {
                "pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt"}
)
public class CucumberRunnerUtil  {

    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;


    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUpEnvironment(){

    // your setup code e.g. environment set up etc.

    }

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new 
        TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }


    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature",dataProvider = "features" )
    public void feature(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature.getCucumberFeature());
    }


    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] features() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();
    }



    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }


    @AfterSuite
    public void cleanUp(){
        // code to clean resources.
    }
}
```